# What is a more featureful and/or better coded 6800 disassembler for modern machines than f9dasm?

Tags: disassembly, 6800

I'm currently using [this version of f9dasm] on Linux to disassemble a
moderately large Motorola 6800 program ([Altair 680 Basic](https://github.com/0cjs/altair-680-basic),
about 8 KB in size).

f9dasm isn't too bad, but I'd prefer to use something more featureful
and/or easier to modify and extend so I can add features to it more
easily.

Disassembly features I'd like to have include:

- Better handling of ASCII characters with the high bit set.
- Being able to assign one of a choice of multiple symbols with the
  same value, so that I could have e.g. `EXTIO = 0` and `DISKIO = 0`
  in the disassembly and annotate different locations to use the
  appropriate symbol for that code (or no symbol at all). This applies
  both to definitions of constants and to addresses that have multiple
  names because they're used for different purposes in different parts
  of the code.
- A choice of ouput formats, including a "list" format (addresses and
  values on the left) as well as a format suitable for input to an
  assembler.
- The ability to add comments and other text in arbitrary locations,
  not just before the disassembly for particular address.
- The ability to define macros and have the disassembler generate the
  macro call as output when it finds matching code, or at least when I
  ask it to. (This may be asking too much, I know.)

Some of the things that make f9dasm hard to modify and extend (for me,
anyway) are:

- It is mainly large, complex functions rather than smaller, simpler
  ones that are easier to re-use, understand and test.
- Lack of unit tests to make modifying individual functions easier.
- Lack of functional tests to make adding/changing features easier.
- Being written in C rather than a higher-level language (e.g.,
  Python).

I'm specifically looking for something I can run on modern machines
(Linux/Unix strongly preferred), rather than something I'd have to
bring up in an emulator.

Does anybody have any suggestions for me? I'd be willing to consider
adding 6800 support to a multi-architecture disassembler that doesn't
currently support it if the code is in good shape to make that
relatively easy.

Comment: Only 8k? To get that true retro experience I would print it out on fanfold paper in hex and ascii, and then disassemble it by hand!

Comment: I found 6502 disassemblers lacking and ended up [writing my own](https://6502bench.com/). I haven't worked with 6800, so I don't know how much effort would be required to adapt the 6502-centric code to it, but it does check several of your boxes. At any rate, I was lured to the dark side by Microsoft's development tools and it currently only runs in Windows.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ouch! I've tried similar manual processes before (I used to do hand-assembly of 6809 code on paper pads), but I think I'll save myself the time and stick with automated tools for this. :-)

Comment: About 20 years ago I wrote a table driven "universal" interactive disassembler running in a shell. It is quite simple, not to say primitive. My C skills were limited that time. :-} Unfortunately there is just an [old mirror of its internet source](http://bodo4all.fortunecity.ws/misc/disasm.html), but you might to look at it and massage it to your liking.

Comment: @BruceAbbott write your own tool on the same machine also gives a good retro feeling...

Comment: Could the program at the end of this page be something to build on? http://seanriddle.com/willy3.html It doesn't have everything you need, but it seems to be a simple c program that ought to be quite easy to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

I had largely same requirements for similar CPU but ended up using f9dasm. But if you are serious then look at IDA Pro.

Comment: Sadly, it appears that the only version of IDA that will disassemble 6800 code is the Pro version, at $2000 or more. I did spend an hour playing with the free version on an 8086 `BASIC.COM` file, just to get feature ideas, but the documentation seems to be poor and the learning curve huge.

Comment: Yes, unsuitable for one-off private hobby use, as eval versions do not support 6800.